# Refresh Table Only PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So this page is reloding the location from the database.(This part is working).
But my table is not refreshing no matter what i do.I don't want to refresh the whole page onle the table itself
I just Want to refresh the table in some x time but everthing i do it's not  working ,i tried so many times but i can't figure it out.

```
<?php
    $id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? ((int) $_GET['id']) : 0; // if we got input from user convert to numbers else set to 0
    if($id <= 0) // the number must be greater than 0
        exit();

    require_once("db.php"); // connect to the database
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Hello User</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=iw&region=IL&key=AIzaSyDyXdL4cZlxo3ldIuvi6_HpZa2jhj7iOU0&callback=initialize"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>#map { height: 600px; width: 1500px}</style>


<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tablediv').load('googlemaps.php');
        setInterval(refreshTable, 1000);
    }
</script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tracking Program</h1>
    <div id="map"></div> <!-- map div !-->
    <div id="tablediv">
    <table style="background-color: red;" id="tableid" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

<?php
// get all data from the table and print it
if($result = $db->query("SELECT FirstName, Lastname, Id, Phone,Address FROM details WHERE RowNum ORDER BY RowNum DESC LIMIT 1")) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$row['FirstName']; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row['Lastname']; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row['Id']; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row['Phone']; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row['Address']; ?></td>

            </tr>
<?php
    }

    $result->close(); //free the result
}
?>


        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var marker, map; // make them global to get access from other functions

function initialize(myLatlng) {
    myLatlng = myLatlng || "<?php include("lastloc.php"); ?>";
    myLatlng = myLatlng.split(",");
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLatlng[0], myLatlng[1]);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: myLatlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'מיקום אחרון'
    });
}

// ajax request to load last location
function lastLocation(){
    var xmlhttp;


    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){


        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            // method 1
            //initialize(xmlhttp.responseText);

            // method 2
            myLatlng = xmlhttp.responseText.split(",");
            myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLatlng[0], myLatlng[1]);
            marker.setPosition(myLatlng); // update the position of the marker on the map
            map.setCenter(myLatlng); // update the center of the map
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "lastloc.php?id=<?=$id; ?>", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

// timer to refresh the last location we have in the database
setInterval(lastLocation, 5000);


</script>

</html>
<?php
    // close the connection to the datebase
    if($db)
        $db->close();
?>
```

Comment: That might be because PHP is what actually manipulate the table, not AJAX. You need to use API approach, so no PHP on this page, another page (PHP) is providing all values in JSON or XML format. Then JavaScript on this page convert it to objects and write to relevant table cells.